# How to plot two dashed regression lines using GGPlot

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, regression

I am currently in the process of trying two form two dashed lines using the ggplot function. The graph is one that shows two regression lines belonging to two different factor groups. I've been able to make one of the lines dashed, but I am having trouble getting the other line to have dashes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
coli_means  %>% 
  ggplot(aes(time, mean_heartrate, group = treatment)) + 
  geom_point( aes(group = treatment, color = treatment)) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(method = "loess", linetype = treatment, se = FALSE, 
                  group = treatment, color = treatment, show.legend = TRUE))
```

I feel I am missing one simple input. Thanks.

Comment: 1) If you are using `color` and `group` repeatedly, put them in the original call to `ggplot` and **remove them from everywhere else**. 2) Then just do  `geom_smooth(method = "loess", linetype = "dashed", se = FALSE, show.legend = TRUE)`

Comment: To expand on @RuiBarradas's comment, if the `linetype = …` is *inside* the `aes()` it refers to a way to break up the data (I.e. `aes(linetype=treatment)` will assign different linetypes to different factors in the column treatment) if it is *outside* the `aes()` it will change the linetype for all lines created by that layer, regardless of their group/factors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is use `scale_linetype_manual()` and then tell it that both the treatment groups require a dashed line.

Let's start with a reproducible example:

```
# reproducible example:
set.seed(0)
time <- rep(1:100,2)
treatment <- c(rep("A",100), rep("B",100))
mean_heartrate <- c(rnorm(100,60,2), rnorm(100,80,2))

coli_means <- data.frame(time, treatment, mean_heartrate)

# ggplot
coli_means  %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = mean_heartrate)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = treatment)) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(linetype = treatment, color = treatment))+
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c('dashed','dashed'))
```

[image: [Dashed lines for both treatments]